# Need help - Actionscript 3 - PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3

can u help me find out why i got these errors

```
    TypeError: Error #2007: 
    Parameter text must be non-null.
    at flash.text::TextField/set text()
    at Perdigana_Scene3_fla::MainTimeline/completeHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

and this is my code in AS3.0

```
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//hide processing text
processing_mc.visible = false;

var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables  ;

//build submit button
var varSend:URLRequest = new URLRequest("form_parse.php");
varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
varSend.data = variables;

//Build the loading variables
var varLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader  ;
varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

//handler for the PHP Script completion and status;
function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    //remove processing clip
    processing_mc.visible = false;
    name_txt.text = "";
    password_txt.text = "";
    email_txt.text = "";

    //Load the response from php
    status_txt.text = event.target.data.return_msg;

}

//Add event listener for submit button
submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ValidateAndSend);

//function ValidateAndSend;
function ValidateAndSend(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    //validate fields
    if (! name_txt.length)
    {
        status_txt.text = "Please enter your username";
    }
    else if (name_txt.length<=5)
    {
        status_txt.text = "Username must be at least 6 characters";
    }
    else if (password_txt.length<=5)
    {
        status_txt.text = "Password must be at least 6 characters";
    }
    else if (!password_txt.length)
    {
        status_txt.text = "Please enter your password";
    }
    else if (!email_txt.length)
    {
        status_txt.text = "Please enter your email";
    }
    else
    {
        //send the data to PHP
        processing_mc.visible = true;

        //ready the variables in the form for sending
        variables.userName = name_txt.text;
        variables.userPassword = password_txt.text;
        variables.userEmail = email_txt.text;

        //send the data to PHP now
        varLoader.load(varSend);

    }
}
```

When I press the submit button in my ActionScript 3.0 scene it outputs the error said above Please Help!.. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `status_txt.text = event.target.data.return_msg;` most likely is the culprit. `return_msg` is probably `null`; make sure it is not `null`.

Comment: Yep! I suggest you put **trace(event.target.data)** within **completeHandler** function

Comment: Thx guys im really new to flash and just started cn u explain more what will i add in the code thank u

Comment: Ive tried to do the  trace(event.target.data) but still get same error :(

Comment: if `(return_msg==null)`...

Comment: ive tried to remove the line and it now works thx guyssssssssss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set variables to **varSend** just before send it:

```
varSend.data = variables;
varLoader.load(varSend);
```

Comment: yesyesyes :DD ima try to connect it now with a database if it really works

Comment: Great! Please select this answer for your questin.

Comment: it says i need 15 rep to do so sryyy :((

Comment: No problem :) but you could mark as useful answer, or not :o ?